# Why isn't overlay working on all images?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm coding an image overlay w/ jQuery, and I got it working (somewhat).  If you hover over the first image, it successfully appears; however, if you hover over the second one, it doesn't even work.  I don't even know what the problem is!  I think it has to do with unique IDs or whatever.  I tried classes, and it didn't work.

Here is the fiddle :: http://jsfiddle.net/PFWcz/7/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.overlay-link').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).find('.overlay').fadeIn(200);
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).find('.overlay').fadeOut(200);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your `overlay-link` elements your containers from which child elements inherit positions.

```
<a class="overlay-link">
    <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/67256/screenshots/1191507/shooot.png"/>
    <span class="overlay"><i>hellllllllooooooo</i></span>
</a>
```

Your `overlay-link` class needs to have `position: relative` and will define the position and size of it and its children:

```
.overlay-link {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 292px;
    height: 219px;
    margin: 30px;
}
```

Any child inside needs to have `position: absolute` and its width and height set to 100% of the container:

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.overlay {
    background-color: rgba(223, 71, 71,0.70);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: none;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Now when you hover over an element, it will create the overlay over that element and not the other one as you were experiencing earlier.

[image: Hover]

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PFWcz/14/

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues. As esqew pointed out, you're using the same IDs, which must be unique.

Addressing that, you'll still see the "same" overlay in your fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/PFWcz/7/), but it's actually not - you're just now seeing a `position`ing issue.

Take a look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/PFWcz/10/

You'll notice that when you hover over the first image, the red overlay is "1", and when you hover over the second image, the overlay is "2".

Previously (with the "helloooooo" text), the red overlays appeared the same (because of the content and positioning)...

Address the `ID` and `position` issues, and it should work.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating fixed position and ID:

http://jsfiddle.net/PFWcz/16/

The main changes is giving the container (`<div>`) positioning:

```
div {
    float: left;
    margin: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Also, I removed offsets (left, top) and floats, applying those to the parent container. A quick, simple fix.

Comment: Hi Jack, I just checked your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PFWcz/10/ and found the same issue with the position. Can you please re-look at it? Here are the two screenshots of what I see. http://i.stack.imgur.com/xjTfw.png and http://i.stack.imgur.com/K68wx.png.

Comment: Hi @RupamDatta - You're correct. The fiddle was just to demonstrate that the overlays were different, however it was still a positioning issue. I've updated my answer to include a fiddle that does address both the ID and positioning issue. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same `id`, which *must* be unique. Use the `class` attribute.

Comment: But the overlay does not appear on the other image?

Comment: @MatthewKosloski That is an entirely different question altogether.

Comment: Sorry, I want the overlay to be independent.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the answered already said there is issue with the `id`'s, I don't want to repeat. Since you have a multiple place where you want to show some text on rollover, using `class` would be a better solution/way to go ahead with.

Here is the change I did in the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PFWcz/13/)**:

```
.overlay-link { /*This class is added. Since an absolute positioned element places itself relative to its parent who is either a relative positioned element or an absolute positioned element. I made the parent of the .overlay div relative.*/
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ff0;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(223, 71, 71,0.70);
    left: -322px; /*Positioning the .overlay element based on its parents left*/
    width: 292px;
    height: 219px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    top: 30px;
    display: none;
    text-align:center;
}

.overlay i { /*There is no .shot element in the DOM. I replaced it by .overlay*/
    background-color: #df4747;
    border-radius: 999px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 30px;
    top: 80px;
    left: 116px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
```

This is based on my understanding. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here, this is what you want

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D33Yk/**

```
$(window).on('load',function () {
    $('.overlay-link').mouseover(function(){
        var overlay = $(this).children('.overlay');
        var img = $(this).children('img');
        $(overlay).css('left',$(img).offset().left);
        $(overlay).css('top',$(img).offset().top);
        $(overlay).css('width',$(img).width());
        $(overlay).css('height',$(img).height());
        $(overlay).fadeIn(200);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).children('.overlay').fadeOut(200);
    });
});
```

Because you had the overlay positioned absolutely in CSS, both overlays always covered the first image. I now set the `left`, `top`, `width` and `height` in JS, so the overlays cover their respective image.

---

I also changed this in CSS:

```
.overlay {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(223, 71, 71,0.70);
    border-radius: 2px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

- removed the top, left, width, height

---

...and this in HTML (I changed both, but I only show one since they are identical):

```
<div>   
    <a class="overlay-link">
        <img src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/67256/screenshots/1191507/shooot.png"/>
        <span class="overlay"><i>hellllllllooooooo</i></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

- changed all the id's to classes, and removed id where it was not necessary